# TapsGUI is not a valid member of ScreenGui "Players.ugh_puppo.PlayerGui.ClickerGUI"

Tags: lua

got this error while coding "TapsGUI is not a valid member of ScreenGui "Players.ugh_puppo.PlayerGui.ClickerGUI" - Client - LocalScript:8". how do i fix this? after i fixed another problem my clicker stopped working (idk why) and now i have this error, any suggestions?**[strong text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZONt.png)**

Comment: You're trying to index an object that doesn't exist, and without info about the object hierarchy of your game there is no way for anyone to help you. However, I noticed two problems that you didn't ask in your question. Firstly, you wrote `False` instead of `false` on line 7, which evaluates to `nil`. Second, you shouldn't be calling `onButtonActivated` when passing it to Connect, the function must be passed without calling it.

Comment: I noticed another problem: the script is also trying to call the method `addRebirthEvent:FIreServer` on line 12, but `addRebirthEvent` doesn't exist, the variable has never been declared.

Comment: so what should i write? idk how to add the things u told me